# iOS - Replaced back button too close to edge

Tags: ios, swift

I want to globally change the navigation bar back button, so I have this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-100, -5000), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        var backImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "BackButton")!
        backImage = backImage.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20))
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
```

But the back image is too close to the left of the screen. How do I move it farther to the right?

[image]

Comment: Did you try adjusting the `UIEdgeInsetsMake`? You have it there, try: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)`. It won't move the button, but it will move the image over.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just adjust the actual image.

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
        CGSizeMake(self.size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                self.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom), false, self.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.drawAtPoint(origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

For Swift 4:

```
extension UIImage {
    func withInsets(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                   height: size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom),
            false,
            self.scale)

        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: Bless you for posting this code, adjusting alignmentRectInsets caused clipping animation when pushing to another VC

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the `left` position on [`UIEdgeInsetsMake`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIEdgeInsetsMake).

You are already calling it here:

```
backImage = backImage.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 20))
```

Like so:

```
backImage = backImage.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 50))
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the position of the button at all.

Comment: I finally got to test the methods myself, and a slight revision to my first answer works out better (and won't threaten to stretch the image, as `resizableImageWithCapInsets:()` would).

Comment: no matter what I set those numbers to, the back button is not changed visually. The tap target seems to change, though.

Comment: This solution doesn't affect the placement of the image at all in iOS 11.X unfortunately.