# How to horizontally position the backIndicatorImage in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiedgeinsets

I use this code to add the insets to the `backIndicator` image for the navigaiton bar. However this only works for vertical positioning of the image.
I can only move the image towards top or bottom, but not towards left or right.
Looks like left/right inset is not working. I am not sure what could be the issue.

```
 UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0); //(20,0,0,0) works fine
 UIImage *backArrowImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"] imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:insets];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backArrowImage];
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backArrowImage];
```

I also tried this:

```
  UIImage * backArrowImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

If this is not possible, do I need to go back to adding custom back button ?

Answer (score 7):

I've tried so many ways and finally this works for me, you can redraw your pic, do as following:

```
UIImage *arrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_Normal"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(arrow.size.width+10, arrow.size.height), NO, 0); // move the pic by 10, change it to the num you want
[arrow drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 0)];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

then use the finalImage as your backIndicatorImage.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version.  For Image only back btn.  Maintains the swipe to go back built in gesture recognizers for iOS 7+.

```
func setBackBtnTarget(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
    var backImg: UIImage = // Your img
    let leftPadding: CGFloat = 10
    let adjustSizeForBetterHorizontalAlignment: CGSize = CGSizeMake(backImg.size.width + leftPadding, backImg.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(adjustSizeForBetterHorizontalAlignment, false, 0)
    backImg.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(leftPadding, 0))
    backImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImg
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImg

    let backBtn: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: target, action: action)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBtn
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

zhoujialei in a form of extension

```
extension UIImage {
    func translatedHorizontally(by constant: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width + constant, height: size.height)
        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: constant, y: 0.0)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        draw(at: newPoint)
        let translatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return translatedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a image with the positioning already inset so you don't need to do inset after.  It's a hack but it should work

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.4.1)

> If you don't know alignmentRectInsets, you can read [this blog](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-layout-and-alignment-rectangles/) first.

---

For simplify the answer, we need some adjust for image edge insets.

```
extension UIImage {
    func withInsets(_ insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                   height: size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom),
            false,
            self.scale)

        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576128/6113158
>   by *Stefan Kendall*

---

And here are the example for how to use it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavBar(with: backImage)
    }

    func setupNavBar(with backIcon: UIImage) {
        navBarLeftImageInsects = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        if let backImage = backIcon.withInsets(navBarLeftImageInsects) {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
            navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This `withInsets` extension is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576128/2227743 ...